# Why don't work jquery validation for dependent select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have form with dependent select. And I need with  `jquery validation` check what each select complete. Second select get from server with `ajax`.

```
... more fieldes ...
Select Country:
<label for="country"></label><br />
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
</select>
<br /> <br />

Select City:
<label for="city"></label><br />
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
</select>
```

And My Validation:

```
country: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
},
city: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
}
```

But I always get result for not select case. How to fix rules for fields `country` and `city` for correct work. If selected something not default it's valid case, if some field not select it's invalid case only for unselected field. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add the class attribute `required` on both select element.

Like following:

```
<select id="country" name="country" class="required">
```

Please see following example:

```js
$("#btnValidate").click(function() {
  console.log("Form is valid:", $("#frm1").valid())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm1">
  Select Country:
  <label for="country"></label><br />
  <select id="country" name="country" class="required">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
  <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
  </select>
  <br /> <br />

  Select City:
  <label for="city"></label><br />
  <select id="city" name="city" class="required">
  <option value="">Select City</option>
  <option value="T1">Test 1</option>
  <option value="T2">Test 2</option>
  </select>
  <p>  
    <input type="button" id="btnValidate" value="Validate">
  </p>
</form>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example and let me know if it works for you

```js
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        country: { required: true },
        city: {
            required: {
                depends: function(element) {
                    return $("#country option:selected").val();
                }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form>

<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
</select>

<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="Newyork">Newyork</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Answers should be more than just code with a message to see if it works. They should include an explanation of why the original code wasn't working and why your solution does.